# How to stop a macro from repeating when run multiple times?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that I hashed together with the immense help with other users on here.  I then edited it slightly to fit my needs.

Right now, running the macro will have Excel look for any numerical value above 0 in column V of Sheet2.  If a value above 0 exists, copy cells S:V of that same row.  Then Excel will look for the last row that has data in it in column T and move to the next row after.  Excel will then paste the data from cell S:V into this row.  Afterwards, it will go back to Sheet2 and continue to look in column V for the next value that exists and do it all over again until it reaches the end of the column.

My issue is that when you run the macro twice, it will perform the actions as needed twice, resulting in duplicate values.  I want Excel to perform the macro once and then if it is run again, have nothing happen.  I'm trying to prevent human error in case someone accidentally runs the macro twice and doesn't notice it.  Is this possible?

```
    Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim endrow As Long


    On Error GoTo Whoa


    '~~> Sheet Where values needs to be checked
    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    '~~> Output sheet
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Look for last row with data in column T and move to next
    endrow = wsO.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row + 1


    With wsI
        '~~> Find Last Row which has data in Col S to V
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then

            lastrow = .Columns("S:V").Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("S1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lastrow = 1
        End If


        Set rSource = .Range("V1:V" & lastrow)


            If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                If c.Value > 0 Then
                    wsO.Cells(endrow + IRow, 20).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                         .Range("S" & c.Row & ":V" & c.Row).Value
                    wsO.Cells(endrow + IRow, 25).Value = "ID#" & .Range("J" & c.Row).Value
                    IRow = IRow + 1
                End If
            End If

        Next
    End With

 LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Exit Sub
 Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: The simplest way might be to overwrite the results each time. Otherwise you'd need some way of identifying each row that is copied to check whether it already exists.

Comment: @SJR I think that'd work for me...Do you know how I can overwrite the results each time?  I'm just beginning to learn VBA so I don't know very much beyond the basics right now...

Comment: Hi @JDoe - are the IDs unique to the rows of data on the output tab? You could do an `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to make sure the ID doesn't already exist on the output tab

Comment: I think this will do it `endrow=1`. Btw your code as posted has a Next without a For.

Comment: @dwirony the ID's are not unique to the rows unfortunately....but that is a good idea otherwise, thank you for you input

Comment: @SJR where would I place `endrow=1` in the code?  Or would I be replacing `endrow = wsO.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row + 1`?  I think I need that part since it checks column T for the last row with data in it then moves down one.

Comment: @JDoe Then what makes a row considered a duplicate? Whatever that is should be the critieria for the countif

Comment: My suggestion is that you don't want to find the last row and start underneath it, but to start again. In fact, why not clear the usedrange of wsO at the beginning and then you can keep the rest of your code as is?

Comment: @dwirony running the macro will copy the data in cells S:V and paste it in after the last row used in Sheet1 column T.  Running it again will copy that same data and paste it under the data that was just pasted.  I want Excel to recognize that the data is already all there and the macro was already run so it should not run again unless the data was altered in some way.  But I'm not sure if that would be possible to do with VBA...

Comment: @SJR ah I see...I will be running this macro multiple times, each for a different column but pasting into the same sheet, in the columns.  That's why I have the code to find the last row and start underneath it, so that it can be a continuous line of data

Comment: Clearly I am missing something. If you clear the contents of the output sheet you can then run all the code you want and nothing will be duplicated.

Comment: @SJR I apologize for being unclear.  I don't want to clear the contents of the output sheet. I want the macro to paste the copied data 1 row after the last row that has data in column T.  Then if the macro is run again, it should somehow check to make sure this exact data wasn't just pasted in right before.  Is that possible through VBA?

Comment: If you need to preserve what is already there, you need to define what you mean by "exact data" as suggested by @dwirony.

Comment: @SJR the data that must be preserved is sort of dynamic.  It could be more or less rows depending on how much data there happens to be at a given time.  Is there a way to detect what's already there, exclude that from deletion, and only delete the values that the code just pasted then and there?

Comment: When you copy you could add a flag in another column, e.g. a 1 or anything really, and filter on that and delete those rows.

Comment: @SJR that's an excellent idea...is it possible to do this all in one step - filter on the flag, delete the rows, paste the new data in?  So that the end user can just click the button to run the macro so that Excel will copy the data required, go to Sheet1, filter on flag, delete those rows, paste new data in w/ the same flag?  I guess the main part that I'm trying to ask is how to add the code that adds a flag in another column and how to filter and delete those rows before pasting in the new data.

Comment: Yes all that is possible. When you copy each line you just need to add a 1 in column AA or wherever. There are many examples online of code for filtering and deleting. If you get stuck on that I suggest you post a new question on that specifically.

Comment: @SJR I will go ahead and look that up.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to prevent human error (more like a band-aid solution):

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to run this macro? Running it a second time can result in duplicate values! Proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
```

Putting this at the start of your macro can warn the user against running it by accident.

Comment: I like this solution.  If all else fails, I will go with this one.   Even if it isn't as fancy pancy to the end user, it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 1):

As SJR mentioned why not clear the wsO before running the code again:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim c As Range
Dim IRow As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim rSource As Range
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim endrow As Long


On Error GoTo Whoa


'~~> Sheet Where values needs to be checked
Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
'~~> Output sheet
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

wsO.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
'the above line will clear the sheet from Row 2 to the last (in case you have headers, if not then change 2 to 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Look for last row with data in column T and move to next
endrow = wsO.Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row + 1


With wsI
    '~~> Find Last Row which has data in Col S to V
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then

        lastrow = .Columns("S:V").Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("S1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row
    Else
        lastrow = 1
    End If


    Set rSource = .Range("V1:V" & lastrow)


        If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
            If c.Value > 0 Then
                wsO.Cells(endrow + IRow, 20).Resize(1, 4).Value = _
                     .Range("S" & c.Row & ":V" & c.Row).Value
                wsO.Cells(endrow + IRow, 25).Value = "ID#" & .Range("J" & c.Row).Value
                IRow = IRow + 1
            End If
        End If


End With

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this code but @SJR mentioned before that I had a Next without a For.  Where would the For go?  My original macro ran fine without the For but I don't understand why it was able to run fine....but when I try to run the one you posted, it tells me Compile error: Next without For

Comment: Looks like you need a `For each c in rSource` above `If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then`

Comment: @dwirony hm this code seems to erase everything then paste in the data.  I want all data to be kept in tact then to paste the data after the last row in column T with data in it.  My code does that right now but clicking it multiple times continues to paste the data down after the last row with data in it, resulting in duplicate values.  Would it be out of the scope for VBA to be able to stop that from happening?  So that it will recognize that it has pasted that data already and that it should not continue pasting unless the data was changed?

Comment: That's why I suggested something to double check against duplicate values, like an `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` :)

Comment: @dwirony I apologize for not taking your suggestion.  I will give it a try right now to see how it fares.  Do you know where I should put that line of code in the macro?

Comment: @JDoe No worries - you need to tell us what is classifying a row as a duplicate value. If it's not the ID, then what is it? Client name? Date? A combination of the two?

Comment: @dwirony it would be the ID that is the duplicate.  Is there a way to change the code that checks against duplicate values to only check the rows that were just pasted only and nothing before that?  If so, you would have solved my problem all  along!!